# Cycles hair, huge difference in the preview render and the final render

Tags: rendering, hair

When I added hair particles to mesh and stared grooming the fur for a cat model and stared doing test renders, I found a huge difference in the preview render and the final render [image]

this is the final render
[image]

this is preview

is there any way to correct?
the model is using the hair shader with color nothing complex

also is there any work around to render fur in 2.8 eevee using base color texture of cat

please reply 
thank you

Comment: See if the Children Particles are too high.

Comment: If you have a subdivision modifier with different subdivisions in viewport and render, it can cause familiar problem.

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question on the same post. Can you ask the second question (about 2.8) separately?